# Deleting document from Lucene indexing not working in version 34

Tags: java, indexing, lucene

I am using lucene version 3.4.0 and StandardAnalyzer. I am trying to delete the document using document id from indexing but it seems not working.

I tried many diff ways as follow:

1. IndexReader.deleteDocuments(new Term("documentDocId", "LuceneObj:215487"))
2. IndexWriter.deleteDocuments(new Term("documentDocId", "LuceneObj:215487"))
3. IndexWriter.deleteDocuments(query); IndexWriter.commit();

But none of the above worked. Also i am not able to trace the error.

can anyone help me to trubleshoot the error or find the solution for it?

Comment: I just found the problem, actually i am using ':' in term and lucene standard analyzer couldnt work it out so not result found and it wont delete anything.

Comment: You probably should not be analyzing your id field.

Comment: I have already analyzed it. but the problem was ":" character in value.

Comment: Right, which is why I said you generally should **not** analyze an id.